# C++ Derived class is abstract error

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, abstract-class

I am having a trouble where Dialin, the derived class is abstract.  I'm not sure why since the only virtual function I have has the same parameters and same return types. From what I've read, that's the only restriction, but apparently I'm wrong.

Here's my code:

Header:

```
class Event{
    class ModemSimV2;

public:
    Event( );
    Event( const Event &e );
    ~Event( );

    virtual void process( ModemSimV2 &m ) = 0;

protected:
    int who;        // the number of the user
    int time;       // when the event will occur
    int what;       // DIAL_IN or HANGUP
};


 class Dialin : public Event{
     class ModemSimV2;
 public:
     Dialin( int name = 0, int tm = 0 );
     Dialin( const Dialin &d );
     ~Dialin( );

     virtual void process( ModemSimV2 &m );

 private:
     int who;
     int time;
     int what;
 };
```

---

Source:

```
Event::Event(){
}

Event::Event( const Event &e ) {
    *this = e;
}

Event::~Event( ) {
}

Dialin::Dialin (int name, int tm )
: time( tm ), who( name ) { 
    return;
}

Dialin::Dialin ( const Dialin &d ) {
    *this = d;
}

Dialin::~Dialin( ) {
}

void Dialin::process( ModemSimV2 &m ) {        
}
```

Comment: On a different note, you haven't declared `~Event` as `virtual`, which is usually a bad thing.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for that. I now remember that from my lecture.

Comment: Compiles for me using gcc 4.4.3 on Linux. There are 3 warnings but none of them with regards to that pure virtual function.

Comment: @dbv: Did you try to instantiate `Dialin`? Defining an abstract class won't give an error, but instantiating it will.

Comment: @dbv: It'll compile fine *until* you attempt to instantiate `Dialin`. It's perfectly fine to define a class that's virtual, but you can't instantiate it. For all the compiler knows, however, you could intend to use `Dialin` as a base to some further-derived class (though since `Event::ModelSimV2` is private, the further-derived class wouldn't be able to override the virtual either).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that there are two different forward declarations of a class named `ModemSimV2`:

```
Event::ModemSimV2          // These are different classes
Dialin::ModemSimV2         // with the same unqualified name.
```

In `Event`, the signature of `process()` is:

```
virtual void process( Event::ModemSimV2 &m ) = 0;
```

and in `Dialin` the definition of `process()` is actually:

```
virtual void process( Dialin::ModemSimV2 &m );
```

so the pure virtual function declared in `Event` is not being implemented in `Dialin`.

Comment: +1. Yes, they're two different class, which means `Dialin` doesn't really *define* the *pure* virtual function of the base class, instead it adds a new virtual function.

Comment: @Nawaz, yep. That is what I meant to convey.

Comment: This is a place the new C++11 `override` attribute would be useful -- the compiler would directly tell you (i.e., in an error message) that as it's defined,`Dialin::process` isn't overriding anything.

Comment: So the solution is to move the forward decl of `ModemSimV2` to outside the respective classes.

Comment: @Rob, yep. I just wasn't sure whether to add that or not as it was homework.

Comment: @Robᵩ: Yes, normally. The alternative would be to make it protected in `Event`, and not re-declare it in `Dialin` (and somewhere provide an implementation of `Event::ModelSimV2`). If it's really `::ModelSimV2` though, you're dead on correctly.