# cannot instantiate abstract class but class isn't abstract

Tags: c++, abstract-class

I've looked this up and the closest thing I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093091/c-derived-class-is-abstract-error) except I don't have any forward declarations. I only have one pure virtual function in the base class which I'm implementing in the subclass as follows:

**Command.h**

```
#ifndef _COMMAND_H_
#define _COMMAND_H_

#include <string>
#include "Stack.h"
#include "Number.h"

class Command
{
public:
    std::string cmdType;
    Command(void);
    Command (std::string cmdType);
    virtual void executeCommand(Stack<Number> & stack) = 0;
    ~Command (void);
};

#endif   // !defined _COMMAND_H_
```

**Command.cpp**

```
Command::Command(void)
    :cmdType("")
{}

Command::Command(std::string cmdType)
    :cmdType(cmdType)
{}

Command::~Command(void)
{}
```

**Number.h**

```
#ifndef _NUMBER_H_
#define _NUMBER_H_

#include "Command.h"
#include "Stack.h"

class Number : public Command
{
public:
    Number (float num);
    void executeCommand(Stack<Number> & stack);
    float val;
    ~Number (void);
};

#endif   // !defined _NUMBER_H_
```

**Number.cpp**

```
#include "Number.h"

Number::Number(float num)
    :val(num)
{
    cmdType = "hi";
}

void Number::executeCommand(Stack<Number> & stack)
{
    stack.push((*this));
}
```

***File error occurs:***

```
Error   4   error C2259: 'Number' : cannot instantiate abstract class   c:\...\add.cpp  34
```

**Add.cpp**

```
#include "Add.h"

Add::Add(void)
    :Binary("+")
{

}



Add::~Add(void)
{

}


void Add::executeCommand(Stack<Number> & numStack)
{
    Number num1 = numStack.top(); //THIS LINE HAS THE ERROR
    numStack.pop();
    Number num2 = numStack.top();
    numStack.pop();

    float tempVal = num2.val + num1.val;

    num1.val = tempVal;

    numStack.push(num1);

}
```

**Add.h**

```
#ifndef _ADD_H_
#define _ADD_H_

#include "Stack.h"
#include "Number.h"
#include "Binary.h"

class Add : public Binary
{
public:

  Add (void);
  void executeCommand (Stack<Number> & numStack);
  ~Add (void);

};

#endif   // !defined _ADD_H_
```

Comment: Could you perhaps get rid of all the extraneous whitespace/comments/etc. so that we don't have to scroll up and down?

Comment: Just so I'm clear, `Command` contains a stack of `Number`, and `Number` inherits from `Command`... across two different headers and sources... and that is intentional?

Comment: @thed0ctor: Please show us the error message you get.

Comment: ..and mark the source on the specific line on which said error happens (though I hazard a guess).

Comment: @WhozCraig: Guess we already know where this is heading... ;)

Comment: Yo have a [circular dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) with Command.h and Number.h try to solve this and see if you still have the problem.

Comment: `_COMMAND_H_` is a reserved identifier due to starting with _<capital> and due to starting with an underscore in the global scope.

Comment: I've updated with the information Also @WhozCraig, no Command only has a method that takes in a stack of numbers. Number should only inherit from one header. The stack's header is there so that the number.h knows what a stack is.

Comment: doing the forward declaration fixed it although I've never used one so I'm not sure why it fixed the problem. Thanks guys for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a circular dependency problem.

- `Command.h` includes `Number.h`
- `Number.h` includes `Command.h`

Usually it is solved by replacing one of the includes with a forward declaration, try forward-declaring `Number` in `Command.h` instead of including `Number.h`; move that include to `Command.cpp`.

Comment: is there a reference you recommend on explaining why this worked?

Comment: @thed0ctor: I don't have anything at hand, and you can google it as good as I could. Sorry.